# Why most applications loads Data from Presenter in onResume?

Tags: java, android, mvp

This questions refers primarily MVP pattern in Android development. I noticed that in many examples data is loaded in onResume method, which causes reloading items in lists every time when users comes back to Activity/Fragment.

Best example to share is app from Google Samples [here on Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/). They reloads tasks in onResume method.

**Question**

My question is why most applications loads data in onResume method which gives sometimes bad behavior when we have more complicated views (they just blinks, especially while loading images) instead of loading data once in onCreate / onCreateView method?

Comment: If "they just blinks, especially while loading images", that is unlikely to be a problem tied to `onResume()` versus `onCreate()`. Part of the reason for populating a UI in `onStart()` or `onResume()` is because the data might have changed while the UI was in the background (e.g., by a service).

Comment: What do you mean by problem tied to onResume versus onCreate?

Comment: You are blaming the use of `onResume()` for a problem ("they just blinks, especially while loading images") that I do not believe is tied to the use of `onResume()`. You claim that using `onCreate()` will resolve the problem, and I do not believe that is the case.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how `Activity` and `Fragment` lifecycle methods, and the Android Framework relate to a design pattern (in this case MVP).  MVP can be implemented a dozen ways by a dozen different developers, all following, by definition, the pattern.

Comment: take a look at this article and sample project which might help:
https://medium.com/@m_mirhoseini/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21#.6y9ze7e55